# Stop jQuery Preload after some time

Tags: jquery, preload, preloader

I have this simple `jQuery` preloader `Script` for my website which shows two overlay loading `divs` `(#preload_out and .preload_overlay)` untill the entire page is loaded. After that the `divs` are fading out and my header starts to animate.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#preload_out, .preload_overlay').delay(180).fadeOut(600, function() {
    $('header').addClass('play');
  });
});
```

Is there a way to stop the preloader after some time `(e.g. 2 seconds)`, fade it out and start the header animation although the site is not fully loaded? I want to avoid that the overlay is blocking the whole site, when there are loading issues. 3 seconds should be fine for at least all of my above the fold items. Sometimes there is kind of a bug, where you have to refresh the whole site because the loader keeps working for ages because of server issues.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

one of the approach you can use to solve the problem could be using `$.promise()`

> the $.Deferred(); contains 2 methods $.promise(); and $.resolve(), if
>   the promise is been fulfiled then it gets resolved

**here is a demo**

```js
function first(){
     
             var deffered2 = $.Deferred();

        /*$('#preload_out,        .preload_overlay').delay(180).fadeOut(600,function({
          $('header').addClass('play');
        });*/

        $('.box').fadeOut(3000,function(){deffered2.resolve();});
            return deffered2.promise();
     }
 
     function second(){
           console.log('now 2d executes');
           $('.box2').fadeOut(9000);
      }
      
     first().done(function(){
        second();
     });
```

```css
.box{
          width:100px;
          height:100px;
          background-color:blue;
          position: absolute;
        }
        .box2{
          //margin-bottom: 9em;
          bottom:1em;
          width:100px;
          height:100px;
          background-color:red;
          position: absolute;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
```

**UPDATE:** as per the requirement

```js
  /*$('.preload_overlay').delay(180).fadeOut(600, function() {
    $('header').addClass('play');
  });*/
  
  function first(){
     
      var deffered2 = $.Deferred();
   
 $('.preload_overlay').delay(180).fadeOut(6000,function(){deffered2.resolve();});
            return deffered2.promise();
     }
 
     function second(){
           console.log('now 2d executes');
           $('header').addClass('play');
           // $('header').addClass('play').fadeOut(1200);  if you want it to fadeOut  after some time then you can do it like so
      }
      
     first().done(function(){
        second();
     });
```

```css
header {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  animation: move 2s;
  background: lightgreen;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes move {
  from {
    height: 50px;
  }
  to {
    height: 150px;
  }
}

.play {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.preload_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  z-index: 999999;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preload_overlay"></div>
<header></header>
```

Comment: How to implement this into my code? Can you help? :/

Comment: if you create fiddle with your html and css then i can show you how to implement it

Comment: I think you got me wrong :/ I want to fadeout .preload_overlay (not header) either when the site is fully loaded OR when 3 seconds have passed and site is still not fully loaded. Most of the cases the site is loaded within a second.. But sometimes it takes much longer and i want to avoid it to load more than 3 seconds. Thank you!